# How to preserve HTML format when creating a task from an email in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, html, tasks

In Outlook 2010, when I create a task from an email, HTML format of email is destroyed, images and tables disappear. How can I preserve HTML format when I create a task from an email?

Comment: Where have you looked to find a solution to this?  What have you tried?  Have you googled this or looked at the M$ site?

Comment: Yes I have looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer. If I  could, I wouldn't ask it here, right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it, as the Tasks don't support HTML (only plain-text or RTF).

As well, Outlook currently provides no options to manually assign the Tasks (default) format.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing a normal drag and drop operation by holding down the left mouse button, perform a right-drag operation by holding down the right mouse button as you drag the e-mail onto the Tasks button. When you right-drag, a menu will appear as soon as you drop the e-mail onto the task button:

Using right-drag to create a task

Select Move Here as Task with Attachment or Copy Here as Task with Attachment. Select the Move option to create a Task and remove the original e-mail from the Inbox; select the Copy option to create a Task and leave the original e-mail in the Inbox.